# MatrixMatrixMultiply error invalid arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, maple

I am working on a procedure on Maple and it is generating a error. While i do the same steps outside the procedure and i don't get any error! (Error, (in LinearAlgebra:-Multiply) invalid arguments.

This is my Maple code:

```
Transform := proc (A, T)
local TI, TD, M, N, K, R, B;
TI := MatrixInverse(T, method = pseudo);
TD := Map(diff, T, x);
M := MatrixMatrixMultiply(A, T);
N := MatrixMatrixMultiply(TI, M);
K := MatrixMatrixMultiply(TI, TD);
R := N-K; B := Map(simplify, R, x);
RETURN B
end proc
```

Thanks forward for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make the second line of your procedure

```
uses LinearAlgebra;
```